# How to make react-sidebar close when any link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, trying to make this component work: https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar

It works, except the sidebar does not close when a link is followed. How do I make a click on a sidebar link close the sidebar?

from index.js:

```
 render((
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route component={Nav}>
          <Route path="/pages/page1" component={Page1}/>
          <Route path="/pages/page2" component={Page2}/>
          <Route path="/pages/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/users/firsttime" component={UsersFirsttime} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/users/firsttime" />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app'));
```

from nav.js:

```
  render () {
    const sidebarContent = <SidebarContent />;

    const contentHeader = <span>
        {this.state.docked || <a onClick={this.menuButtonClick} href="javascript:void(0);" style={styles.contentHeaderMenuLink}>=</a>}
        <span>This title</span>
      </span>;

    const sidebarProps = {
      sidebar: sidebarContent,
      docked: this.state.docked,
      sidebarClassName: 'custom-sidebar-class',
      open: this.state.open,
      touch: this.state.touch,
      shadow: this.state.shadow,
      pullRight: this.state.pullRight,
      touchHandleWidth: this.state.touchHandleWidth,
      dragToggleDistance: this.state.dragToggleDistance,
      transitions: this.state.transitions,
      onSetOpen: this.onSetOpen,
    };

    return (
      <Sidebar {...sidebarProps} >
        <MaterialTitlePanel title={contentHeader}>
          {this.props.children}
        </MaterialTitlePanel>
      </Sidebar>
    );
  }
```

from sidebar_content.js:

```
const SidebarContent = (props) => {
  // const style = props.style ? {...styles.sidebar, ...props.style} : styles.sidebar;
  const style = props.style ? update(styles.sidebar, { $merge: props.style }) : styles.sidebar;

  // const links = [];

  const handle = () => {
    console.log('handle');
  };

  return (
    <MaterialTitlePanel title="Travel Guide Mobi" style={style}>
      <div style={styles.content}>
        <Link to="/pages/page1" >Page 1</Link>
        <div style={styles.divider} />
        <a key="key1" href="#" style={styles.sidebarLink}>Cities & Events</a>
        <a key="key2" href="#" style={styles.sidebarLink}>Set Travel Plans</a>
        <div style={styles.divider} />
        <a key="key3" href="#" style={styles.sidebarLink}>Edit Profile</a>
        <a key="key4" href="#" style={styles.sidebarLink}>Logout</a>
      </div>
    </MaterialTitlePanel>
  );
};
```

I thought maybe write something like `<Link to="/pages/page1" onClick={self.props.closeMenu}>Page 1</Link>` but I'm not sure how to do it exactly?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Probably (1) keep a state in the component, isSidebarOpen, and toggle it true/false; then (2) on action such as link click, change it to false. The accepted answer describes a similar implementation. This is a typical UI design pattern.

Comment: can you please share me your code, i m in trouble and having same problem

Comment: @JunaidShaikh This was 7 years ago - no I don't have that code anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are thinking is correct. You can have a boolean state variable in Nav component which decides the visibility of the sidebar.

**Nav.js**

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {showSidebar: true} // Initially we want it to be visible
    }

    toggleSidebar = () => {
        this.setState({showSidebar: !this.state.showSidebar})
    }

    render() {
        return <Sidebar 
                 toggleSidebar={this.toggleSidebar}
                 showSidebar={this.state.showSidebar}
               />
    }
}
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        const {toggleSidebar, showSidebar} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                <Link to="/pages/page1" onClick={toggleSidebar}>Page 1</Link>
                {showSidebar?Code for open sidebar:Code for closed sidebar}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can obviously change the conditional rendering part. For example if you want to handle it through css, you can change the className dynamically depending upon the value of **sidebarVisible** variable.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I m facing the same issue , your solution works, sidebar gets closed onClick of link, but it does not linking me to anywhere, it just closes and page does not changes, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the router state. Design your showSidebar link like:

```
<Link to="/pages/page1" state={{ sidebarOpen: true }}>Page 1</Link>
```

And in your Nav component read the `sidebarOpen` value from router state.

**Why?**

- Now you have the option to open the sidebar from anywhere in your application without any additional prop passing. Just set the state of the link.
- Any other click would close the sidebar which I think is what you want.

In fact I would simply NOT recommend what you've proposed in your original post without some kind of an event bus (e.g: flux actions) because you'd probably end up with a large plate of spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

in sidebar_content.js:
`<Link style={styles.sidebarLink} to="/cities" onClick={this.props.onClickHandle}>Cities & Events</Link>`

in nav.js:

```
  render () {
    const sidebarContent = <SidebarContent onClickHandle={this.onClickHandle} />;
...
```

and in nav.js again:

```
export default React.createClass({
     onClickHandle () {
        console.log('onClickHandle');
        this.setState({ open: false });
      },
```